# Perforce: Any way to run 'p4 changes' without a clientspec?

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec

I know that generally, when running `p4 changes` you need a clientspec specified, so that Perforce can limit the results properly.

Yet, in P4V, you are allowed to operate in a "no workspace selected" mode, and you can view changes, etc.

I want to do something similar from a script, but the only way I can think to accomplish this is to:

1. Create a temporary clientspec, with some general `//depot/...` mapping
2. Perform my operations (eg: `p4 changes blabla`)
3. Delete the temporary clientspec

But I don't want to have all these temporary clientspecs being created/destroyed all the time. P4V doesn't seem to be doing that in its "no workspace selected" mode.

Is there a way to acomplish the same, from the commandline?

Comment: `p4 changes -m1 //...` seems to work for me even without a client set. What error are you getting?

Comment: Hmm, maybe my problem really boils down to "How do I tell Perforce to use *no* clientspec". If I run `p4 client -o` right now, it gives me a clientspec based on some default choices, which has the wrong stuff mapped. I want to specify explicitly: *no clientspec at all, please*

Comment: Run `p4 set` and that should not only tell you what your `P4CLIENT` is set to (which you probably know) but also give you a hint about which [mechanism](https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.1/manuals/cmdref/set.html) (environment variable, `p4config`, registry, etc.) has been used to set it. Then undo that setting.

Comment: The "undo that setting" is the sticky bit — I don't want to make any permanent changes (such as changing registry settings, moving .p4config files, etc). I just want to temporarily run without the clientspec. Or maybe equivalently, with an "everything" clientspec.  Maybe this isn't possible.

Comment: If you want to temporarily run with a different clientspec, use the "-c" global option (see "p4 help usage"), e.g. "p4 -c tempcli changes".  But this is not necessary for the "p4 changes" command in the first place -- see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your client spec doesn't matter at all if you provide a depot path to the "p4 changes" command.  Just run:

```
p4 changes //depot/...
```

or whatever command you were going to run with your temporary "//depot/..." mapped client spec.

Your client spec will ONLY come into play if you use an argument that is explicitly client-relative, such as a local file path, the #have revision specifier, et cetera.  If you don't use a client-relative argument, it doesn't matter if your clientspec is undefined, if it maps only one file, or if it maps the whole world, you'll get the same results from "p4 changes" regardless.

Comment: Ah, seems right. I had been confusing myself because i was using `-c myclient` and `//myclient/...`, but that clispec was empty.